# iOS 11 - Search controller shadow on status bar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, ios11

I have problem with searchController when I'm using presentViewController, status bar have shadow - I don't want this. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

we on the same boat, check it here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86828